# Google Geocoding API returning wrong address when changing street number

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

This is the weirdest thing I've come across by using Google Maps/Geocoding.

Simply by changing the street number, Google Geocoder returns a completely different (and wrong) address.

Correct result:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Theodor-Heuss-Platz+3,+48599+Gronau,+Germany

> Theodor-Heuss-Platz 3, 48599 Gronau, Germany
>   Latitude: 52.211915,
>   Longitude: 7.0223971

Wrong result:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Theodor-Heuss-Platz+4,+48599+Gronau,+Germany

> Theodor-Heuss-Straße 4, 53177 Bonn, Germany
>   Latitude: 50.6804364,
>   Longitude: 7.1609145

The request for street number 5 is working properly again. It seems that only street number 4 is not okay.

I checked the other solutions around here, like replacing ampersands with HTML codes. However, this URL is already clean.

Google Maps returns the correct addresses in both cases, but Geocoder fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this work:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Theodor-Heuss-Platz+4,+Gronau,+Kreis%20Borken,+Regierungsbezirk+M%C3%BCnster,+North+Rhine-Westphalia,+48599,+Germany

If you think it is a bug, you can consider reporting it here:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Also consider using OpenStreetMap Nominatim, they have better support for EU countries:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim